# BindRequired on DateTime

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

I have an issue with [BindRequired] attribute, it does not invalidate my model state:

```
public class PostModel
{
    [BindRequired]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
public class BindTestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("test")]
    public IActionResult SetValue([FromBody] PostModel request)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

if I post a body like this:

```
{}
```

My modelstate is valid.
What is the good way of validating that `Date` is present on my body, and invalidate the model ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `RequiredAttribute` to your `DateTime` property, then you need to make the `DateTime` nullable, otherwise you will get the default value for `DateTime` which is `{0001-01-01T00:00:00}`.

So basically do the followings:

```cs
public class PostModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

---

Regarding why the `BindRequired` did not work, I think (not 100% sure, it is just what i think) that since you are using `[ApiController]`, it first would use `[FromBody]` by default, then the binding would happen after the `Json.NET` deserialization, so when the `deserialization` happens the DateTime value would be set to the `Default(DateTime)`. To solve this you can use the old way as shown above instead of using `BindRequired`, or add `[JsonRequired]`.

**Note:** when you use `[JsonRequired]` with `[ApiController]`, validation happens before it hits your endpoint. Also note that `BindRequired` works well with normal MVC Controller.

Comment: too bad we can't use [BindRequired] and avoid extra code with nullable values

Comment: I update the answer to explain the reason (not fully sure though about it) :D.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal MVC controller" ?

Comment: When you do not use `ApiController`, because `ApiController` would add `[FromBody]` to your action, and the binding would be a bit different (as described in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RequiredAttribute` instead of `BindRequiredAttribute`. In ASP.NET Core, the latter is only applicable for “non body” parameters